# Openshift Mysql 5.5 cartridge how to access logs?

Tags: mysql, logging, openshift, mysql-workbench

I need to review the mysql 5.5 server logs but I cannot find a way to get access them via ssh, sftp or mysqlworkbench. The mysql cartridge is in a scaled application. A solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things here I'd like to point out that should provide some more information on how things work and how to get to the information you're looking for.

1. Scalable applications with DB's actually have the DB running in a separate gear than the application framework (for scaling purposes). For instance, if you ran `rhc app show <appname> --gears` for one of your scalable applications you would see that there are 2 gears being used and that the ssh information for each of them is different. So if you're just looking to take a quick look at your logs via ssh, you'll need to ssh into the appropriate gear to get to them.
2. You will need to use the `rhc port-forward` command to forward the right local ports to your database gear and then be able to connect mysqlworkbench from there.

Comment: Thanks, I have now access to the logs via sftp and ssh. But there is almost nothing in it. How can I activate the error log and the general query log? Besides, I have an error in mysqlworkbench when I try to access the logs: "Unexpected error creating log reader: [Errno 2] no such file or directory in [...]/mysql/stdout.err. But the file exists on the server!?